# lighting rail of two light fixture one turn on faintly the other not at all

Tags: lighting

i have a fixture with 2 bulbs one of the lamps goes on very faint the other does not go on at all I checked connections put in new bulbs 48'

Answer (score 2):

My psychic powers (required for deciphering your question) suggest that you have a two-tube 48 inch (not foot) florescent fixture.

Sounds like you need to replace the ballast. They don't live forever.

Comment: I think the collective agrees with your psychic powers @Ecnerwal +

Comment: In this case, 48" stoplight, you will also find out that replacing the entire fixture is less than the cost of the ballast alone.

Comment: My word, Tyson - you have psychic powers beyond mine if you can determine what type of fixture this is.

Comment: I meant "shop light" but my phone thinks it's smarter than I am.

Comment: My limited psychic powers figured that was what you meant, but they fail to see anything in the question that identifies this as a shop light, .vs. a puff, a troffer, a strip, or any of a wide variety of other 2-tube 48" fixtures. I'll also note that a replacement ballast costing more than a cheap shop light may well be a lot better than the very cheap ballast in the cheap shop light - though we are nearing the point where "replace them all with LEDs" is the smarter and cheaper option.